# How to implement UPI Autopay in springboot project

Tags: spring-boot

I want to implement UPI autopay in my money saving app,

enabling users to set target saving amounts and choose recurring payment schedules (weekly, monthly, or yearly) for automatic debiting from their linked accounts.

can i implement without any third party service provider ?